# How to enable the typeover action in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

As someone somewhat active editor in SE, I have the need to edit several post per day. Some of them would be easier if I have the "Replace"/"Typeover" (the action when you press <kbd>Insert</kbd>) in Firefox. I've not able to activate this function nor I have figured out if I need an option before hand. So, how do I replace/typeover text in any text area in Firefox?

I'm not going to find and replace stings, but typeover while writing as I can do with a text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bug 38415](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38415) this is a known issue and it's marked as **WONTFIX**. Firefox is always in insert mode and that's that.

You're probably better off looking into extensions like [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/its-all-text/), for instance. This extensions allows you to edit textareas using an external editor of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to replace words with other words, Firefox has several add-ons you could use. I have found the link for the general search:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/tag/replace

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just from reading the reviews it looks like FoxReplace is a safe bet. that's here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxreplace/reviews/

Comment: No, I want to replace characters as I write.

Comment: Oh, misunderstood. Sorry.